# Copy only new data from one workbook to a separate 'master' copy

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet where i need to add turnarounds times for each assessment. I might do 20+ assessments in a day and there will be a new row for each assessment. 
At the end of each day i need to click a command button which will update a master copy my boss will have only new data entered from that day or the day before if i forget...

```
Sub CompareArrays()

Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, nextRow As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim x As Boolean

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm") 'Name of first workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx") 'Name of second workbook
arr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:O" & wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
arr2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:O" & wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
k = 1
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    x = True
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(j, 1) Then
            x = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If x = True Then
        k = k + 1
        pos = Application.Match(arr1(i, 1), arr1, False) + 1 
        nextRow = wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wb2.Sheets(1).Rows(nextRow).EntireRow.Value = wb1.Sheets(1).Rows(pos).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The above code does not work at all but its the best i can figure out...I just need all new data from the last time i hit that commandbutton to be copied From A:O into a master workbook.

all i'm getting at the moment no matter that kind of code i try (and i have tried a good few!) keeps kicking back a script 9 error!!!

PLEASE HELP!

Thank you!!!!

Comment: Please read> [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: it's above, ive been tweaking it and trying to get it work but i keep getting a script error

Comment: Instead of comparing the arrays and trying to send the rows that are not present, would it not be simpler if you were to add a flag on say column P that its either true or false as to whether this has already been copied over? this way your code will run faster too....

Comment: thank you, i'll read up on how to do that and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply add to column P of wb1 the words "Sent" or "Not Sent" and then use the following code:

```
Sub CompareArrays()
Dim i As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm") 'Name of first workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx") 'Name of second workbook
LastRow = wb1.Cells(wb1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'check last row of wb1

For i = 2 To LastRow ' loop through wb1 to check if sent or not
    If wb1.Cells(i, 16).Value = "Not Sent" Then 'if not sent then copy the range from A to O, not including the helper column P
        NextfreeRow = wb2.Cells(wb2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A" & NextfreeRow & ":O" & NextfreeRow) = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i & ":O" & i).Value
        wb1.Cells(i, 16).Value = "Sent"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a play

Comment: Please do bear in mind that the For Loop will begin from row number 2, as I assumed that you will already have headers in place...